# How do I export a JavaFX project from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

For java swing I've always exported my project as a runnable jar file, but with javafx this doesn't seem to work. When I export my javafx project as a runnable jar file, then click on the jar file, nothing happens. The program only runs when I run it with a batch file. Does anyone know why it does this and how to fix it?

Comment: Have a look at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: I'm not using gradle or maven, and I'm using java 8. I'm not sure where to look in that link.

Comment: Wix toolkit for exe. For Java 8, you should not have an issue creating a jar.

Comment: You need to run the jar from the command line to see what errors you are getting.

Comment: I have run the jar from the command line, it only works when I run it from a command line, as well as the wix toolkit is for visual studio, and I use eclipse.